# How should I use NPM modules in Jenkins that I don't want in the build itself?

Tags: jenkins, npm, devops

What are the best practices when using development modules such as Mocha or Browserify, which are needed during the build process but not in the built artifact itself? The only options I can see are:

1. Pre-arranging these modules to be installed globally on the build server (not likely possible in my case)
2. Run `npm install -g` explicitly as part of the build process for each module (Feels somewhat wrong to install globally)
3. Don't use the `--production` flag on npm install (which forces these modules to be present in the final artifact, increasing its size and defeating the purpose of dev/production dependencies)

Comment: Why not just use a regular `npm install`? Generally *none* of the `node_modules/` are actually part of the artifact. If you really need to, you can use [`npm prune`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prune) post-build to strip out those development dependencies.

Comment: Are they not? I assumed it would be packaged with everything needed to run, to eliminate the chance of dependency versions being different from what was tested. Maybe I'm wrong there